# Selenium webdriver wait for background XHR requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, selenium, xmlhttprequest, webdriver

I'm trying to automate something on Salesforce using Selenium. How do I wait until the search results are displayed as in the screenshot? Method-1 or Method-2 ?

[image]

```
//Method-1
public void waitForPageLoadXHR(WebDriver driver) {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
            driver1 -> ((JavascriptExecutor) driver1).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
}

//Method-2
    public void waitForPageLoadXHR(WebDriver driver) {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
                driver1 -> ((JavascriptExecutor) driver1).executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0"));
    }
```

**Update:** Here's a representation of the HTML. I'm sorry I cannot post the actual HTML due to compliance issues. The < input > is my textbox and search results are the < li >s'. The < li > appear dynamically as I type.

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the HTML (or at least a representative snippet of HTML) for the auto complete suggestions? You will likely need to wait for an element to appear inside that auto populated list, rather than trying to wait for AJAX to complete.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB I have already copy pasted my code and tagged the question with relevant tags so that it's searchable. The HTML is quite long and will not add any value-add to the question, let alone affecting search-ability as mentioned in the link that you posted. However, I understand that it might affect users with screen-readers, but sorry I still cannot post the actual HTML, since it contains identifiable information of my client.

Answer (score 0):

(1) I saw you are searching an Account and sending string on global search field of Salesforce page. My first suggestion here is 'Do not copy and Paste' your account (or any name) directly here. Salesforce Lighting is heavy site and takes more time than usual sites. So what you can do is - give character by character with little wait. 
I know this trick you might not like but it's working for me 100% - see below code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++){
   char character = value.charAt(i);
    String inputCharacterText = new  StringBuilder().append(character).toString();                  
    driver.findElement(webElement).sendKeys(inputCharacterText);
    Thread.sleep(50);
    }
```

(2) You Primary question's solution:

TestWait.waitForElementToBeVisible(driver,PageClass.searchAccount(driver));

this is your WebElement: (Since you are searching specific Account then try to make your xpath using Title using custom text  -example of xpath "//*[@title='AccountName']")

```
public static By  searchAccount= By.xpath("You XPATH go here ");

public static By searchAccount(WebDriver driver) {

    return searchAccount ;
}
```

Please use the wait method mentioned below, it's working amazing for me:

class is "TestWait" and you defined method below in the class

public static boolean waitForElementToBeVisible(WebDriver driver, By expectedElement) {

```
    boolean webElement = false;
    logger.info("Executing waitForElementToBeVisible for page element");
    try {
        logger.info("Waiting for web element " + expectedElement + " with fluent wait");

          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          Wait<WebDriver> wait = new
          FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
          .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(45))
          .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(200))
          .ignoring(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.class,org.openqa.
          selenium.StaleElementReferenceException.class)
          .ignoring(org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException.class);

          wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(expectedElement));    

        webElement = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(expectedElement + " : Not found the element on Page");
        webElement = false;
        Assert.fail("WebElement is not visible");
    } finally {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TestConstant.ImplicitWaitTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    return webElement;
}
```